# Displaying JSX/HTML based on props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

What is this kind of expression called and how or when should it be used?

```
{props.type === "big" && <h2>{props.title}</h2>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` part is a *JSX expression* that allows you to embed JavaScript code in JSX markup.

The `&&` is a logical AND operator, but in JavaScript, instead of resulting in either `true` or `false`, `&&` does this:

1. Evaluates its left-hand operand
2. If the value from Step 1 is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the `&&` operation takes that result as its result and stops here
3. If the value from Step 1 is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) *(the opposite of falsy)*, the `&&` operation evaluates the right-hand operand and takes that value as its result

So `props.type === "big" && <h2>{props.title}</h2>` means:

- If `props.type` is `"big"`, put `<h2>{props.title}</h2>` here.
- If not, put nothing here (because React doesn't render `false`, `null`, or `undefined`)

> how or when should it be used

It's typically used when you need to render something conditionally. The condition is the first part (`props.type === "big"`). The thing being rendered, or not being rendered, is the second part (`<h2>{props.title}</h2>`).

Comment: Thank you so much this was really helpful and has also provided me a new trick to render jsx conditionally much appreciated!